# What Mercurial DVCS hosting would you recommend for a small open source project?

Tags: mercurial, hosting, dvcs

I'm looking around for free Mercurial hosting for a small-scale open-source project.
If you've ever used such a service, who is doing the hosting, and would you recommend them?

I know SF.net can be **[set up](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/index.cgi/MercurialOnSourceforge)** to host HG repos, but it looks like a lot of trouble (for the benefit of having a big, known, service that's unlikely to go down anytime soon).

There's also the [list of free HG hosts](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/index.cgi/MercurialHosting) right in Mercurial's official documentation, but I'd like to hear from those that actually got down and dirty with it :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[update] **[Bitbucket stopped hosting Mercurial](https://bitbucket.org/blog/sunsetting-mercurial-support-in-bitbucket).**

[BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org/) is certainly the most popular. I've experimented it for while, then I jumped into git.

Comment: +1 as well - BitBucket is great.  You get repository hosting, a version-controlled wiki and a great issue tracker for free!

Comment: Bitbucket also lets you to create a private repository in the free plan

Comment: @idursun make that *unlimited* private repos for free

Answer (score 1):

I use Bitbucket for a bunch of Open Source projects and am very happy with it, too.

Answer (score 1):

[sourceforge.net](http://www.sourceforge.net) just added Mercurial, Bazaar and Git support.

Answer (score 1):

This wasn't the case when this question was originally asked, but since January 2010 Microsoft's [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/) can host Mercurial repositories as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Project Kenai](http://kenai.com/)? I have an account but have not hosted any projects there so I can't comment on the quality of service.

Comment: Oracle has just announced that Project Kenai is going to be discontinued: http://www.oracle.com/technology/community/sun-oracle-community-continuity.html

Answer (score 0):

For small code examples and if you don't need a wiki and stuff, you could try http://freehg.org else you should give http://www.sharesource.org a chance.
Or just use Mercurial as intended by publishing your source decentralized to other developers using the integrated webserver for example :).

Comment: freeHg seems to be down now; so it's no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket is the best hoster i have encountered so far.

The service is fast and rock-solid and the staff is very fast at addressing any itch you might have.